# CIFilter works when built for 32-bit, but doesn't appear when built for 64-bit?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, 32bit-64bit

I have an XCode project that I originally set up to build to either 32 or 64 bit. Part of the code creates a layer with a border, and then adds a "bloom" filter to create a glowing effect around the border:

```
// Create a layer with just a border
CGColorRef yellowColour = CGColorCreateGenericRGB(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
CALayer *selectionLayer = [CALayer layer];
selectionLayer.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, size.width, size.height);
selectionLayer.borderWidth = 3.0f;
selectionLayer.borderColor = yellowColour;
selectionLayer.position = CGPointMake(100, 50);
selectionLayer.zPosition = CGFLOAT_MAX; // stay on top

// Add a bloom filter to add a glow to the border
CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIBloom"];
[filter setDefaults];
[filter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:5.0f] forKey:@"inputRadius"];
[selectionLayer setFilters:[NSArray arrayWithObject:filter]];
```

When I build this project as a 32-bit app, the layer appears, and the yellow border correctly has the glowing effect applied.

If I then build and run in 64-bit, the layer does not appear at all (i've tried changing the background colour to make sure the layer is visible)

If I comment out the line that adds the filter, the layer reappears with its yellow border (but with no filter applied to it).

As soon as I switch back to 32-bit again, it all works fine.

What am I missing here? Do I need to change frameworks or change some other build flag so that the filter will work in 64-bit mode?

Comment: Not gonna solve the problem, but you appear to be leaking `yellowColour`.

Answer (score 0):

This is very old, but for somebody happening onto this: I found that `zPosition = CGFLOAT_MAX` can be the culprit. 64 bit `CGFLOAT_MAX` is much bigger from 32 bit, and somehow it prevents the layer from being visible at all. If I want to ensure something is always on top, I just use a self defined large number, like `zPosition = 1000.0f`.